# can't see output on emacs running oz (mozart 2)

Tags: emacs, emacs24, oz, mozart

I started an online course which requires using emacs editor with oz language. OS - Windows 7

when i feed the code, it seems as if the code is compiled correctly but nothing is showed in the emulator window.

In the messages buffer i get the message:

```
Error during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 98) signaled (wrong-type-argument markerp 1)
```

any ideas?

Comment: In case this course is public, interested to know the location.

Comment: Do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, this will give you a stacktrace when the error occurs, post it here, it will help people trying to help you. Also post the emacs version you are using.

Comment: @IqbalAnsari, in the end, i just decided to try and install oz, emacs and ActiveTcl again. and voila, it worked. I still don't know why but i guess something just went wrong during the first installation.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler, the course name is "Paradigms of Computer Programming" runnig on the EdX platform: https://www.edx.org/course/louvainx/louvainx-louv1-01x-paradigms-computer-1203. It just started 2 days ago so you can definitely join it

Answer (score 0):

I changed my system path from `c:\mozart2-2.0.0-alpha.0+build.3777.4c64bf5-x86-windows\mozart\bin` to `c:\mozart\mozart\bin` and similarly for Emacs (removed all Unicode characters in the path as suggested in the course wiki).